# Access foreign relationship field through template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have this model in a phoenix app.

```
defmodule Rumbl.Video do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "videos" do
    field :url, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :description, :string
    belongs_to :user, Rumbl.User
    belongs_to :category, Rumbl.Category

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w(url title description)
  @optional_fields ~w(category_id)

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end

end
```

And the category field represents a relationship to a Category model which has a field called name.

Then in the template I have this:

```
<%= for video <- @videos do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= video.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= video.url %></td>
      <td><%= video.title %></td>
      <td><%= video.description %></td>
      <td><%= video.category_id %></td>

      <td class="text-right">
        <%= link "Show", to: video_path(@conn, :show, video), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Edit", to: video_path(@conn, :edit, video), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Delete", to: video_path(@conn, :delete, video), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I can access video.category_id

How can I access video.category.name to make it more human readable?

Edit: Video controller index and categories part

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller

  alias Rumbl.Video

  def action(conn, _) do
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
          [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
  end

  def index(conn, _params, user) do
    videos = Repo.all(user_videos(user)) |> Repo.preload(:category)
    render(conn, "index.html", videos: videos)
  end

  alias Rumbl.Category

  plug :load_categories when action in  [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  defp load_categories(conn, _) do
    query =
      Category
      |> Category.alphabetical
      |> Category.names_and_ids
    categories = Repo.all query
    assign(conn, :categories, categories)
  end
end
```

Comment: make sure you preloading relation, and after this you can access via `video.category.name`. Take a look at this article - https://robots.thoughtbot.com/preloading-nested-associations-with-ecto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're loading the videos like this in your controller:

```
videos = Repo.all(Video)
```

This will not load the associated records. For that, you can use [`Repo.preload`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3):

```
videos = Repo.all(Video) |> Repo.preload(:category)
```

Now each video will have their `category` field loaded with all their fields and you can do `<%= video.category.name %>` in the template.

Comment: I added the preoload to the pipe: videos = Repo.all(user_videos(user)) |> Repo.preload(:category) but it complains function nil.name/0 is undefined or private at <td><%= video.category.name %></td>

Comment: I added in the question part of my video_controller's code

Comment: Looks like that specific user does not have a `category` assigned (`category_id` would be nil as well). Not sure what you want to do in that case, but to output nothing for that case, you can do `<%= if category = video.category, do: category.name %>`.